# PHP: svn_update and shell_exec("svn up ".DIR)

Tags: php, svn, shellexecute

Whats the difference between a [svn_update](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-update.php) and doing a `echo shell_exec("svn up ".DIR)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the big block of text that says:

This function is EXPERIMENTAL. The behaviour of this function, its name, and surrounding documentation may change without notice in a future release of PHP. This function should be used at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the 2 operations to be the same as the svn php module tries to be a "native" svn client.

There could be differences in the versions of the 2 clients (php client versus command line client).

You may want to check if the svn user used for both commands is the same. In the php client you must use [svn_auth_set_parameter](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-auth-set-parameter.php) to setup the credentials of the svn user

I hope this will help you,

Jerome Wagner